# How to level uneven screed?

Tags: floor, leveling

In my < 10 m^2 basement I have a screed floor which either from the beginning or over the years (some decades) has the following deficits:

- uneven thickness (10 to 50 mm judjing from the sides of a few smaller holes)
- makes an uneven floor with height differences up to 50 mm.

I'm not the owner, so the best option to replace the complete floor is not an option because the property management is incapable of accepting useful contributions to the house in case they're involved.

The charge is max. 2 people and some tools with < 100 kg/m^2. The house has stripe foundations. Under the screed floor is sand.

So, I assume my options are:

- adding something on top, which could be

  - wood panels, but that's a lot of measurement and cuts and requires to add at least another 10 cm taking into account the height differences and the basement is humid or
  - levelling compound or a similar compond/concrete, but I assume for thickness < 10 mm it will crack after some months under load and levelling compound is not for use without a cover (tiles, etc.) afaik
- removing the highest irregularities which still leaves the problem with the joints where pieces with < 10 mm thickness will crack and requires renting a relatively expensive milling machine

There're no lines running in the floor.

Comment: There is no best option to start modifying a property that you do not own. As a renter you really have to accept what you walked into and if it is not suitable leave and find another place.

Comment: I disagree, as I currently have a tenant who has made very nice improvements to my property with a little communication. Also, that's not the question.

Comment: @isherwood - "a little communication" is all fine and dandy. But I hope you have some type of written agreement from the tenant that specifies that they release all claim and entitlement related to the changes that they have made whether or not you gave them some type of consideration for same such as a rent adjustment. Good intentions between people can be fine today but you can never anticipate how people's attitudes can change when circumstances are different.

Comment: I appreciate the hints, but let's just assume that it's possible. I mentioned the fact that it's a rental only in order to explain why I won't do the complete basement floor.